Kafka schema registry unable to connect to bootstrap server running with KRaft in .net Aspire
Im trying to setup a local test environment with a Kafka server and schema registry using the .net Aspire framework.
The Kafka server is working fine and accepts messages however the schema registry is unable to connect to the server.
The error message is :
Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

The process roles of the kafka server is broker,controller
The docker images used are: confluentinc/confluent-local version 7.6.0
and confluentinc/cp-schema-registry version 7.6.1
Aspire packages versions are: 8.0.0-preview.6.24178.5
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS = PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
The external port of the kafka server is 29092.
I have tried finding a solution for hours now, does anybody have any ideas to test?

It's connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:54891, so that would need to be one of the advertised listener, or some other configuration needs to use port 9092/29092

I thought the advertised listeners was for within the container.
I tried changing the port to both 29092 and 9092, I cannot connect using any of them.
I saw you commenting on my other question (with docker compose), do you have any ideas who to incorporate that solution within this context?

It's not clear to me where port 54891 comes from. Is that something set in aspire?

Its a random port generated by Aspire. It can be manually overridden for the external ports.

I changed the port number in the question text to make it clearer.

In your Compose file, you have 9092:9092, so that's the only port that's accessible from the host, which also means you'll need to set localhost:9092 as one advertised listener and then broker:29092 for anything within the Docker Compose network, as mentioned in the other comment

Ok, I’m not sure that there is a notion of the custom hostname in aspire. Is there any way around that?
